# Can I Add Related Tables to a PowerApps Canvas App?

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have inherited a PowerApps Canvas app that uses SQL Server as it's data source. The tables involved are Customer, Project and Work Order.

I’m building a Create Work Order Screen that requires the Customer ID, Project ID and Work Order Item IDs. The tables have foreign key relationships. How do I add all required tables as a collective data source?  It seems that Canvas PowerApps are limited to single entities but need to confirm this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like by enabling some Experimental switch, you can achieve this.

Basically you have to add extra screens, Data sources and then simple formula will do the trick for you to set/filter/choose the related records.

> Reversing the Relationship: One-to-Many
>   For every Many-to-One relationship, there is a corresponding One-to-Many when coming from the other direction.  Making the One-to-Many relationship easily accessible is the feature we are introducing this week.
>   To get started, go to the File menu, App settings, Advanced settings, scroll to end of the list, and turn this switch on:
>
> [image]

[One-to-Many Relationships for Canvas apps](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/one-to-many-relationships-for-canvas-apps/)